# Optional templates in go html/template?

Tags: templates, go

Given a set of templates like:

#### layout.tpl

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some title</title>
{{template extracss}}
</head>
<body>
<h1>Page title</h1>
{{template content .}}
</body>
</html>
```

#### home.tpl

```
{{define "content"}}
<p>page content goes here</p>
{{end}}
```

#### edit.tpl

```
{{define "content"}}
<form>form content goes here</form>
{{end}}

{{define "extracss"}}<style>body{background:pink}</style>{{end}}
```

using this to render the template:

```
func Render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpname string, data interface{}) {

    t, err := template.ParseFiles("views/layout.tpl", "views/"+tmpname+".tpl")
    // parse error
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }

    if err := t.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

edit.tpl will render correctly as it has 'extracss' defined, home.tpl will not as the template parser rightly says 'no such template "extracss"'.

So what mechanism would I use to allow 'optional' templates to be used?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty define works: `{{define "extracss"}}{{end}}`. It's maybe not super elegant, but simple to understand.

Note that you don't need to repeat the empty defines. You can put them into your master template and redefine them in the included templates only if needed.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but as you say it's not elegant.  I'm being pragmatic at the moment and going with this but am hoping for something better.

Comment: "Elegant" is a vague term. What's the actual problem with it? It communicates to the reader that other templates might fill something in here.

Comment: The only problem is that the actual templates I'm using have more than just 'extracss' as an optional part. I also have 'extrajs' as well, and can see more being created as the product builds.  Having to have empty defines in each and every template seems wrong somehow.

Comment: You don't need to repeat them. You can put the empty defines into your master template, and then redefine them in the included templates only if needed. In your example, move the empty define from edit.tpl to layout.tpl.

Comment: aha, now that is better than I was doing.  Excellent, thanks.

Comment: @ThomasKappler I know this is an old answer, but I would recommend editing your comment about empty defines into the main answer.  That was the part I needed, and this answer wouldn't really have solved my problem without it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @thomas is awesome, but I found what he wrote ambiguous and wasted a lot of time trying to translate it into code.

Here's code that works (and I believe is what he's suggesting):

#### layout.tpl

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    {{template extracss}}
    {{define "extracss"}}{{end}}
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page title</h1>
    {{template content .}}
  </body>
</html>
```

#### home.tpl

```
{{define "content"}}
  <p>page content goes here</p>
{{end}}
```

#### edit.tpl

```
{{define "content"}}
  <form>form content goes here</form>
{{end}}

{{define "extracss"}}<style>body{background:pink}</style>{{end}}
```

using this to render the template:

```
func Render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpname string, data interface{}) {

    t, err := template.ParseFiles("views/layout.tpl", "views/"+tmpname+".tpl")
    // parse error
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
       
    if err := t.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this wasn't available at the time the question was asked but it seems that you can use `block` for this purpose:

> **`{{block "name" pipeline}} T1 {{end}}`**
>
> A block is shorthand for defining a template
> `{{define "name"}} T1 {{end}}`
> and then executing it in place
> `{{template "name" pipeline}}`
> The typical use is to define a set of root templates that are then customized by redefining the block templates within.

#### layout.tpl

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    {{block "extracss" .}}{{end}}
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Page title</h1>
    {{block "content" .}}{{end}}
  </body>
</html>
```

#### home.tpl

```
{{define "content"}}
  <p>page content goes here</p>
{{end}}
```

#### edit.tpl

```
{{define "content"}}
  <form>form content goes here</form>
{{end}}

{{define "extracss"}}<style>body{background:pink}</style>{{end}}
```